# QGIS Web Client - postgreSQL Layers wouldn't shown

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-web-client

since updating my QGIS to version 2.8.3 the postgreSQL Layers wouldn't shown in the QGIS web client.

In the Desktop version the project works very well

I only can see the projecttitle and the groups where the layers in.

Have anybody some idea ?

Comment: Have you tried to set up a new connection?

Comment: Yes i tried with the old connection and with the new connection.

Comment: QGIS Desktop is still working normally?

Comment: in the Desktop Version it works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried writing a comment but ran out of characters...

I also had the same problem. But in my case, when I started the desktop version it always asked me for password and username of the connection.

Now if in the connection you dont specify save user/pass, it wont write it in your .qgs file -> `<datasource>dbname='DB_NAME' host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='password' sslmode=disable key='ogc_fid' srid=3787 type=Polygon table="public"."somelayer" (wkb_geometry) sql=</datasource>`

This is how the correct data source should be, and this is the datasource you get when you skip the save password part: `<datasource>dbname='DB_NAME' host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' sslmode=disable key='ogc_fid' srid=3787 type=Polygon table="public"."somelayer" (wkb_geometry) sql=</datasource>`

Suddenly your web client wont be able to connect to the database because there is no password provided, so your qgis webserver wont return anything.

Comment: thank's for your hint. I had saved my password and the datasource looks like yours

Comment: ok, do you get any errors in browser console output when it fails to load?

Comment: Sorry, No i doesn't

Comment: projects which I had created some time ago also work with postgresql. First after updating to QGIS 2.8.3 i get these problem

Comment: Well I'm using qgis (used 2.8.2. before) 2.10. and I have no problems. Did you try creating a fresh project and added some random layers, just for testing to see if they load in QGISWC? This way you will know for certain if there is a problem with your project or if the problem is hiding somewhere else.

Comment: I made a new project and it works well with shp or sqlite data Only PostgreSQL has some problems

Comment: Ah ok. So even with this new project the postgresql arent shown (even the names of the layer aren't shown) in QGISWC.

Comment: Yes. Only the postgresql layers in my old project working fine in the QGSIWC

Comment: Yes nothing shown. Only the projecttilte and the layergroups

Comment: I saw that in my old projects the datasource only consists of <datasoruce>PG:dbname='...' user='...' password='...'|layername=...

This is the only difference which i can see

Comment: Aha, well maybe my definition of datasource does not match yours. What is the definition of the datasource in the new file? Is it similar to the old one? And are there any important things missing like passwords or username. In my database I call the layer with table= and layername is defined later on by qgis <layername>Something</layername>

Comment: in the new project the datasource looks like yours.

Comment: I'm not really sure what is causing this problem. Maybe you could try checking the GetCapabilities request to see if the layer that is missing is listed in there and then later on not displayed in the QGISWC, then the problem would be with the client. Another reason you could check is if you get any errors from your qgis web server, since its not showing your layer, the error should be there. Also could you paste the old datasource so I can see what it was defined like in the old version of qgis desktop.

Comment: Testing the GetCapabilities in the new file don't display the layers. That's why i think the problem is the server.

My old datasource where all is working correctly is:

<datasource>PG:dbname='...' user='postgres' password='...'|layername=....</datasource>

If you mean this

Comment: Do you know Why are the parameters of the datasource has changed?

Or how can i load the postgre data in the old format. 

Because there it  works

Comment: I think that, with the new version of QGIS desktop there was a change in the datasource definition. Maybe the version of the qgis web server has also changed, meaning that maybe you should upgrade the webserver aswell. But before doing any of that you should check what is bothering the web server, first I would give it same parameters that you give via URL with GetCapabilities request but using cmd. That way you should get all the errors shown in cmd. If you're using linux just use console then. Then maybe you will learn more about what is going wrong.

Comment: i found out that they have changed the datasource in combination with the <provider encoding... in the newer version.

I changed it in the xml-code back and now it works well

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad you resolved your problem. Will you answer your question, so I can delete this one?

Comment: THANKS for helping me. Yes if you want you can delete it

Answer (score 0):

i found out that they have changed the datasource in combination with the provider encoding... in the newer version. I changed it in the xml-code back and now it works well.

THANKS for the help Ena2345